# Stop while loop with HTML button arduino

Tags: javascript, html, c++, arduino, esp32

Hello I  am working on a project with an esp32 (IDE arduino) and I am trying to start / stop a while loop with 2 html button.

I have a webpage with html and js.
When I click the button start, it send a command string and same for the stop : here is the part code of the js function.

```
    <p>
  <button type='button' id='BTN_START'>
    Start
  </button>
</p>

<p>
    <button type='button' id='BTN_STOP'>
      Stop
    </button>
  </p>

</span>

</body>

<script>
  var Socket;
  var isTransmitting = false;

  document.getElementById('BTN_START').addEventListener('click', StartTrans);
  document.getElementById('BTN_STOP').addEventListener('click', StopTrans);
  
  function init() {
    Socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/');
    Socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      processCommand(event);
    };
  }
  

  function StartTrans() {

    var msg = {command:'start_transmission'};
    Socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }

  function StopTrans() {

    var msg = {command:'stop_transmission'};
    Socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
```

In the arduino when i receive the text "start_transmission" it runs the code inside the loop, but when I send the "stop_transmission" it does nothing.

here is the code : of the function to receive websocket event.

```
void webSocketEvent(byte num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Client " + String(num) + " disconnected");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Client " + String(num) + " connected");
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      String command = "";
      StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, length);
      if (!error) {
        command = doc["command"].as<String>();
        Serial.println("Received command: " + command);
      }
      
         do
        {   
            int data = ShortRead();
            Serial.print("Force is: ");
            Serial.println(data);
            delay(1000);  
            if(command == "stop_transmission"){break;}    
         } while (command == "start_transmission")
         
        
        Serial.println("");
      break;
  }
}
```

I tried to use a volatile bool value that changed when I send the stop command, but it didn't work either.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you loop in do/while indefinitely without updating command.

I use a boolean global var to enable reading after receiving start command and disable it after stop command.

EDIT3 : move read data in loop and remove delay() to avoid blocking loop and missing socket packet.

```
boolean startRead = false;
unsigned long tw;

void loop() {
  if (millis() - tw > 1000) {  //non blocking wait 1 sec
    if (startRead) {
      int data = ShortRead();
      Serial.print("Force is: ");
      Serial.println(data);
      tw = millis();           //raz time wait
    }
  }
}

void webSocketEvent(byte num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Client " + String(num) + " disconnected");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Client " + String(num) + " connected");
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      String command = "";
      StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, length);
      if (!error) {
        command = doc["command"].as<String>();
        Serial.println("Received command: [" + command + "]");
      }
      
      if (command == "start_transmission") {
        startRead = true;
      }
      else if (command == "stop_transmission") {
        startRead = false;
      }
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("Data type not managed");
  }
}
```

Comment: This will create an infinite loop and never check the command == "stop_transmission". 
It is still the same issue

Comment: This mean it's mandatory to exit the event function and wait for next message. That's why I clarified in comment "assuming command is updated in realtime in event handler". I update answer.

Comment: Ok sorry didn't see it. 
but I dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean webSocketEvent is fired each time a new message arrive. if you stay inside function and wait, you'll never get news messages. you must exit function and wait for next webSocketEvent, process the message, exit and so on. 
Have you try my edited code ?

Comment: It works but it does it only one time because it is not in a while loop.

Comment: OK second edit : try it.

Comment: Hi it is still not working.

Comment: I just realized that the `Delay(1000)` in Loop prevents the program from reading the data that arrives. I replaced it with a non -blocking Delay (Edit3). I also added `serial.print` to identify everything that happens. to be continued...